# mb_strtoupper not recognizing quotes

Tags: php, text, character-encoding

I'm having problems with `mb_strtoupper`. I need it to capitalize a text that is in a newsletter generated in PHP (so I cant just capitalize it with css, and is stuck using a PHP function that will capitalize the text)

Thing is, `mb_strtoupper`works fine, but has a problem with the quote `'` character. A text like `Bob's Burgers` is being converted to `BOB&RSQUO;S BURGERS`

Is there a way to make `mb_strtoupper` leave the quote alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the encoding as the second parameter in mb_strtoupper like so...

```
mb_strtoupper("Bob's Burgers", 'UTF-8');
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php

Comment: Copy pasting the Bob's Burgers from this answer works, but not when I'm doing shift+, myself. Maybe my french canadian keyboard is dumb and is not giving me the same exact character. I fixed it by a ducktape way, doing a str_replace. $titleCap = str_replace('&RSQUO;',"'",$titleCap);

Answer (score 1):

That's because your text is not `Bob's Burgers` but `Bob&rsquo;s Burgers`. In other words, you don't have plain text but HTML and `mb_…` functions do not have builtin HTML parsers.

It can be really tricky because HTML is a full-fledged language. If you do not expect HTML tags (e.g. `Click <a href="//example.com">here</a>`) you can try something like this:

```
$data = 'Bob&rsquo;s Burgers';
// 1. Convert to plain text
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
// 2. Upper case
$data = mb_strtoupper($data, 'UTF-8');
// 3. Encode back to 7-bit ASCII
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
var_dump($data);
```

> ```
> string(19) "BOB&rsquo;S BURGERS"
> ```

([Online demo](https://3v4l.org/l4WON))

Step #3 should not really be necessary but I guess you have HTML entities for some reason :-?

Comment: I'd wager that the entities are there because OP's app "has trouble with special characters being mangled" due to encoding mismatches. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Sammitch Certainly, HTML entities must be already there, there's no way to produce them out of the blue with `mb_strtoupper()`. People don't always make a clear distinction between HTML source code and the rendered view. The answer by WebCode.ie is wrong and even the OP acknowledged so—right after accepting it...

Comment: The Green Checkmark of Ultimate Truth applied to an incorrect answer?! Hold the line while I light the beacons and call for aid!